# preg_replace specific sql columns in php

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, row

So I have code that goes something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM LIST"
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div class=\"leftcol\"><p>".preg_replace('/\b0\b/', 'NA', $row["info"])."</p></div>
      <div class=\"rightcol\"<p>".preg_replace('/\b0\b/', 'NA', $row["stuff"])."</p></div>";
```

That works for them rows fine. But then I run into the problem where I need to use multiple replaces on $row["info"] AND $row["stuff"]. I would like to replace \b1\b with another word but at the same time as \b0\b.

What works best for this? Would there be something that does this better outside of the P tag or SQL info all together?

Comment: Why are you assigning a variable in the middle of the `echo`? What do you use `$text` for?

Comment: Oh I guess that just doesn't need to be there. I just put that in there from when I Iearned about preg_replace, I'll edit that out of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the replaces before you echo the html, eg:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $text = preg_replace('/\b0\b/', 'NA', $row["info"]);
    $text = preg_replace('/\b1\b/', 'NA2', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\b2\b/', 'NA3', $text);

    $text2 = preg_replace('/\b1\b/', 'NA2', $row["stuff"]);

    echo "<div class=\"leftcol\"><p>".$text."</p></div>
          <div class=\"rightcol\"<p>".$text2."</p></div>";
```

Comment: This works just fine for what I'm doing. I use `money_format` for the numbers and I use `preg_replace` to change the numbers to font. I could just use an if statement to make this work right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple replacements by giving an array of patterns and replacements:

```
$info = preg_replace(array('/\b0\b', '\b1\b'), array('NA', 'NA2'), $row['info']);
```

So your code would look like:

```
echo "<div class=\"leftcol\"><p>".preg_replace(array('/\b0\b', '\b1\b'), array('NA', 'NA2'), $row["info"])."</p></div>
      <div class=\"rightcol\"<p>".preg_replace(array('/\b0\b', '\b1\b'), array('NA', 'NA2'), $row["stuff"])."</p></div>";
```